# Real time value saving in filesystem from a html site

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems

I want to read the values from one website and save them in a file in real time. I know that this isn't possible with javascript. The website is in an external server and I can't run in locally.

I can see the values in inspect on my browser in real time. Is there a way to just print some of them in a file?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are talking about web scraping and I would suggest BeautifulSoup (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Or take a look at [StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the case, because the values that I want are changing all the time by me, so it's like a session or something.

Comment: Show us your code. What did you try? What specific values did your code reveal, and what values would you prefer to see instead? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve